# Inheritance and 2 interface types

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I have a question regarding inheritance and designing a user interface.

I have a `class KeyboardKey` which represents an individual keyboard key, such as Q, W, E, R, ... etc.

I have a `class Keyboard` which contains a **vector of** `class Keyboardkey`. [Important!]

I am using SFML, and so each time an event is generated from an event loop, it is sent to the keyboard class. This class then farms that event out to the corresponding key.

In addition, I have a `class SynthesizerKey` which inherits from `KeyboardKey`. In addition to the regular key stuff, such as "is the key enabled", "is the key pressed", this class contains data and functions to handle generating a sin wave tone. Variables include the amplitude and current phase of the sin wave.

I am now about to create a `class SynthesizerKeyboard`. I was about to copy and paste all the code from `class Keyboard` into this class, however this is not good programming practice, as code is duplicated!

The main issue I have is that `SynthesizerKeyboard` contains a function to generate a sequence of samples to be stored in a buffer. In order to generate the samples, a loop iterates over each `KeyboardKey` and checks if it is pressed. If it is, then we must generate a sample corresponding to that keys note/frequency.

However, since the vector contains `class KeyboardKey` and **not** `class SynthesizerKey` I do not have the variables for the phase and amplitude of the sin waves as member data of the elements of the vector.

I think I may have to do what is known as "refactoring" [?], and separate the "sin wave" parts of `SynthesizerKey` from the `KeyboardKey` parts. In other words, I ditch the `SynthesizerKey` class and have an `Synthesizer` class and a `KeyboardKey` class, separately. I then have a vector of `Synthesizer` in `class SynthesizerKeyboard` in addition to the vector of `KeyboardKey` in `class Keyboard` which I have access to in `SynthesizerKeyboard` through inheritance.

However this is less elegant. Is there another way?

Below is some code which might help the reader understand the quesiton in more detail.

**SynthesizerKeyboard**

```
class SynthesizerKeyboard : public Keyboard
{

public:

    SynthesizerKeyboard(const sf::Font& sf_font)
        : Keyboard(sf_font)
    {
    }

    double Sample() const
    {
        for(std::vector<KeyboardKey>::iterator it = m_keyboardkey.begin()
            it != m_keyboardkey.end(); ++ it)
        {
            if(it->IsKeyPressed())
            {
                it->Sample();
            }
        }
    }

    void GenerateBufferSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16> buffer)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < buffer.size(); ++ i)
        {
            buffer[i] = Sample();
        }
    }

};
```

**SynthesizerKey**

```
class SynthesizerKey : public KeyboardKey
{

protected:

    AbstractOscillator *m_abstractoscillator;

public:

    double Sample() const
    {
        return m_abstractoscillator->Sample();
    }

};
```

**Keyboard**

```
class Keyboard
{

protected:

    std::vector<KeyboardKey> m_keyboardkey;

public:

    Keyboard(const sf::Font& sf_font)

    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)

    void Event(const sf::Event& event)
    {
        for(std::vector<KeyboardKey>::iterator it = m_keyboardkey.begin();
            it != m_keyboardkey.end(); ++ it)
        {
            (*it).Event(event);
        }
    }

    bool IsKeyPressed(const sf::Keyboard::Key& sf_key)
    {
        for(std::vector<KeyboardKey>::iterator it = m_keyboardkey.begin();
            it != m_keyboardkey.end(); ++ it)
        {
            if((*it).Key() == sf_key)
            {
                return (*it).IsKeyPressed();
            }
        }
    }

};
```

**KeyboardKey**

```
class KeyboardKey
{

protected:

    KeyState m_keystate;
    sf::Color m_pressed_color;
    sf::Color m_release_color;
    sf::Text m_sf_text;
    sf::Keyboard::Key m_sf_keyboard_key;
    sf::RectangleShape m_sf_rectangle;

public:

    KeyboardKey(const sf::Keyboard::Key& sf_keyboard_key, const std::string& text, const sf::Font& sf_font,
                const double position_x, const double position_y)

    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)

    void Event(const sf::Event& event)

    bool IsKeyPressed()

};
```

Comment: You can compartmentalize the code you are worried about duplicating in `AbstractKeyboard` complete with pure virtual specialization functions implemented by `AbstractKeyboard`'s inheritors to be called from `AbstractKeyboard` when, for example, `Moog`-specific behaviour is required. `AbstractKeyboard` also contains a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<KeyboardKey>>` so that `KeyboardKey` or appropriate subclasses can be contained without memory management woes.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure that I completely understand your suggestion in detail... could you explain this further to me, or perhaps add a suggested answer, perhaps with example?

Answer (score 0):

Going to skip over the keys for now, but you should consider something similar for them.

First define a bare bones abstract that performs all of the common tasks and includes hooks for the classes that specialize the abstract to fill out to perform their particular behaviour:

```
class AbstractKeyboard
{
protected:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<KeyboardKey>> m_keyboardkey;
    void Draw();
    void Event()
    {
        for(auto &key: m_keyboardkey)
        {
            key->Event();
        }
    }

    bool IsKeyPressed(const sf::Keyboard::Key& sf_key)
    {
        for(auto &key: m_keyboardkey)
        {
            if(key->isKey(sf_key))
            {
                return key->IsKeyPressed();
            }
        }
        return false; // need this to handle the no match case, otherwise undefined behaviour
    }
    void doStuff()
    {
        // generic keyboard stuff goes here
        doSpecificStuff();
    }
    virtual void doSpecificStuff() = 0;
public:
    AbstractKeyboard(const sf::Font& sf_font);
    virtual ~AbstractKeyboard();
};
```

All keyboards have keys, so the vector of keys goes here. Note that we've gone from a `vector` of keys to a `vector` of smart pointers to keys. Now we can have any key that inherits the basic key, synthesizer key for example, and the smart pointer eliminates the usual memory woes of dealing with pointers.

The big takeaway here is the `doStuff` function. It does stuff. What is up to you. When it's done doing the basic stuff that all keyboards must do, it calls `doSpecificStuff`, a function that each inheritor must fill out, even if it does nothing. `doSpecificStuff` does whatever the inheritor does differently, add extra behaviours, and generally makes a synthesizer more than just a regular keyboard.

Here is the basic keyboard:

```
class Keyboard:public AbstractKeyboard
{
protected:
    void doSpecificStuff()
    {
        // Do keyboard Stuff, if there is any specific stuff to do
    }
public:
    Keyboard(const sf::Font& sf_font): AbstractKeyboard(sf_font)
    {

    }

};
```

It doesn't do anything special, but it could but putting special code into `doSpecificStuff`.

The synthesizer adds a few functions for folk who know it is a synthesizer (`Sample` and `GenerateBufferSamples`) as well as implementing `doSpecificStuff` to do synthesizer stuff.

```
class SynthesizerKeyboard : public AbstractKeyboard
{
protected:
    void doSpecificStuff()
    {
        // I do specific stuff! Yay me!
    }

public:

    SynthesizerKeyboard(const sf::Font& sf_font): AbstractKeyboard(sf_font)
    {

    }

    // leaving these as an example of how to get a SynthesizerKey out of m_keyboardkey
    double Sample() const
    {
        // just going to sum because I don't know what's supposed to happen in here
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(auto &key: m_keyboardkey)
        {
            if(key->IsKeyPressed())
            {
                if(SynthesizerKey* skey = dynamic_cast<SynthesizerKey*>(key.get()))
                {
                    sum += skey->Sample();
                }
                else
                {
                    // like freak out, man.
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    void GenerateBufferSamples(std::vector<sf::Int16> buffer)
    {
        for(sf::Int16 & val: buffer)
        {
            val = Sample();
        }
    }

};
```

Since the synthesizer uses synthesizer keys, `Sample` contains an example of how to turn a pointer to a regular key into a synthesizer key and trap a configuration error that places the wrong type of key into `m_keyboardkey`

By adding a virtual destructor and the virtual keyword to `Sample` in `SynthesizerKeyboard`, we could also make a

```
class MoogSynthesizer: public SynthesizerKeyboard
{
public:
    double Sample() const override
    {
        // I do Moog sampling!            
    }
}
```